# Comparision of topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$  be two different topologies on X. If convergence in $\tau_1$ implies convergence in $\tau_2$then$\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$.
How to prove it by using the definion"  $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$ if $U\in \tau_2$ then $U\in \tau_1$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not in general true, at least if convergence is meant to be for sequences.  I'll come to a counterexample later. If we are talking about convergent nets of filters (which are equivalent views) it is true.

It *is* true for for sequences in so-called [sequential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) spaces, where a set is closed iff it is sequentially closed.

The proof is then obvious: if $F$ is closed in $\tau_2$, let $x_n \rightarrow x$ be a convergent sequence under $\tau_1$, where all $x_n \in F$. As convergence in $\tau_1$ implies convergence in $\tau_2$, we know that $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $\tau_2$ as well. As $F$ is closed in $\tau_2$, it is sequentially closed (this holds in all spaces), so $x \in F$. Hence, $F$ is sequentially closed in $\tau_1$. If we know assume that $(X,\tau_1)$ is a sequential space, we know that $F$ is closed in $\tau_1$. So $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$ (if we have inclusion for the closed sets then also for the open sets, which are the complements).

The same proof would work for *all* spaces if convergence is considered for nets instead, as closed is the same as "net-convergence-closed" in any space.

If $X = \mathbb{R}$, consider $\tau_1$ the co-countable topology, and $\tau_2$ the discrete topology. Then $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $\tau_1$ iff $\exists N \forall n \ge N: x_n =x$ and this implies $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $\tau_2$ (in fact in any topology).
But the co-countable topology is not finer than the discrete one (just the opposite in fact).